# Why doesn't “ping -l” works when ping works?

Tags: ping

I can ping

```
ping AddressIp
64 bytes from indirizzoIp: icmp_req=1 ttl=42 time=149 ms
```

but with additionnal parameter

```
ping AddressIp -l 1400 
ping: cannot set preload to value > 3

ping AddressIp -t -l 1400
ping: can't set unicast time-to-live: Invalid argument
```

Why can't I ping?

Comment: Sorry in not -p is -t. I root:root@ado-BackBox:~# ping AddressIp -t -l 1400

Comment: Type `id` in the console

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ping AddressIp -l 1400 
ping: cannot set preload to value > 3
```

You need superuser rights to access this feature of `ping` with a value more than 3.

Try:

```
sudo ping AddressIp -l 1400
```

**UPDATE:**

Do you want a "size" option for your `ping` packets? I guess, in Windows option `-l` means "size of the packet", but in Linux there is another option for that.

Try `-s` option:

```
sudo ping  AddressIp  -s 1000 -l 1400
```

**DE BENE ESSE**

In Linux `ping` is going until you stop it, so you don't need the Windows `-t` option.

Answer (score 6):

From `ping's manpage`:

```
-l preload
       If  preload is specified, ping sends that many packets not waiting 
       for reply.  Only the super-user may select preload more than 3.

-p pattern
       You may specify up to 16 ``pad'' bytes to fill  out  the  packet
       you send.  This is useful for diagnosing data-dependent problems
       in a network.  For example, -p ff will cause the sent packet  to
       be filled with all ones.
```

So make sure you run ping under super user and feed to `-p` option an argument.